# Is there a reason why I am getting the same input over and over even though I am using np.random.choice()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, data-science

I am given that someone playing Dungeons and Dragons (D&D) rolls a fair die with values 1-20 (one value per side) and that depending on the character I guess there is a modifier for each action that the character can make. In this case the modifier is 11 for opening a door. If the dice roll + modifier is greater than 15, the action is successful and the character opens the door if not, the action fails. This part of the question wants us to make an array of seven dice rolls and the score for that character with the modifier of 11.

This is what I have tried so far

```
import numpy as np
from datascience import *

modifier = 11
possible_rolls = np.arange(20)
roll_result = np.random.choice(possible_rolls)
modified_result = roll_result + modifier
num_observations = 7

def simulate_observations():
    """Produces an array of 7 simulated modified die rolls"""
    possible_rolls = np.arange(20)
    roll_result = np.random.choice(possible_rolls)
    modified_result = roll_result + modifier
    array = make_array()
    for i in np.arange(num_observations):
        array = np.append(array, modified_result)
    return array

observation_array = simulate_observations()
print(observation_array)
```

I'm expecting to get a various range of outputs based on a random roll of the dice and then adding that value to the modifier, then finally placing that final value in to the array named `array` but all I am getting is an array that looks like `[20.,20.,20.,20.,20.,20.,20.]`. Any ideas as to where I may be off? I'm 90% sure my issue is in my for loop as I have not quite grasped what exactly I am doing in them but I can't seem to pin down exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you call `np.random.choice`only once, instead of once in each iteration in the for loop

```
import numpy as np
from datascience import *

modifier = 11
possible_rolls = np.arange(20)
roll_result = np.random.choice(possible_rolls)
modified_result = roll_result + modifier
num_observations = 7

def simulate_observations():
    """Produces an array of 7 simulated modified die rolls"""
    possible_rolls = np.arange(20)

    array = make_array()
    for i in np.arange(num_observations):
       # moved roll_result inside the loop
       roll_result = np.random.choice(possible_rolls)
       modified_result = roll_result + modifier
       array = np.append(array, modified_result)
    return array

observation_array = simulate_observations()
print(observation_array)
# [20. 11. 24. 11. 15. 16. 26.]
```

But you can also avoid the for loop and do directly

```
def simulate_observations():
    """Produces an array of 7 simulated modified die rolls"""
    possible_rolls = np.arange(modifier,20+modifier)
    return np.random.choice(possible_rolls,size=num_observations).tolist()
```

Comment: So I tried to do the solution given above and got an array `array([17, 22, 23, 12, 23, 16, 18])` which my grader software is spitting back out the error

`
 > Suite 1 > Case 1

>>> abs(5.7 - np.std([simulate_observations() for _ in range(5000)])) < .2
True
>>> abs(21.5 - np.mean([simulate_observations() for _ in range(5000)])) < .2
False

# Error: expected
#     True
# but got
#     False
`

Comment: If you need a list and not an array, I have added `.tolist()`at the end of my function, does it work as expected?

Comment: @Banani720 why is this second statement `abs(21.5 - np.mean([simulate_observations() for _ in range(5000)]))  < .2 ` supposed to be TRUE ? If you take a lot of simulations you should expect `np.mean(..)` part to be close to the mean of possible rolls which is 9.5 and not 21.5. By the way if you replace 21.5 by 9.5 it works

Comment: If I'm being honest I have no clue still why it is giving this error sometimes we have problems where the grader is off I think I'm going to chalk it up to that until I can go to office hours tomorrow. I did have to add the modifier 11 to each of those 7 random values we pulled.

Comment: ooh sorry I forgot about the modifier part I just added it (possible_rolls has changed) but still the mean should be 9.5+11=20.5 and not 21.5. Try with `modifier=12` to see if it passes

Comment: Yes modifier 12 worked that's very interesting. I'd ask this in chat but I don't have enough reputation, how did you know that that would work out of curiosty?

Comment: You need to have `np.mean([simulate_observations() for _ in range(5000)])` close to 21.5 to pass your second test, if you do a lot of simulations the mean will be close to the mean of possible_rolls, if you take integers from 0 to 20 the mean is 9.5, so you need to add 12 to have a mean around 21.5